# How to fill the ID with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello all and have a nice day,

I would like to remove and replace the old ID with the new ID. For example, I have data like

```
Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
id:72367        Title 1  Step1          Resul1      
                         Step2          Resul2              
                         Step3          Resul3              
                         Step4          Resul4              
                         Step5          Resul5              
                
Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
id:72368        Title 2  Step1          Resul1      
                         Step2          Resul2              
                         Step3          Resul3              
                         Step4          Resul4              
                         Step5          Resul5              

Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
id:72369        Title 3  Step1          Resul1      
                         Step2          Resul2              
                         Step3          Resul3              
                         Step4          Resul4              
                         Step5          Resul5              
                         Step6          Resul6              
                         Step7          Resul7              
                         Step8          Resul8              
                         Step9          Resul9
```

And I would like to modify it to like this

```
Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
1               Title 1  Step1          Resul1      
1                        Step2          Resul2              
1                        Step3          Resul3              
1                        Step4          Resul4              
1                        Step5          Resul5              
                
Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
2               Title 2  Step1          Resul1      
2                        Step2          Resul2              
2                        Step3          Resul3              
2                        Step4          Resul4              
2                        Step5          Resul5              

Test case ID    Title    Step Action    Expected Result 
3               Title 3  Step1          Resul1      
3                        Step2          Resul2              
3                        Step3          Resul3              
3                        Step4          Resul4              
3                        Step5          Resul5              
3                        Step6          Resul6              
3                        Step7          Resul7              
3                        Step8          Resul8              
3                        Step9          Resul9
```

I would like to do it with pandas. Do you have any idea about this one or can you help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Create mask for test not equal `Test case ID`, groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) by inverted mask and set all values in column without matched `Test case ID` and previous rows:

```
m = df['Test case ID'].ne('Test case ID')
mask = m & m.shift(-1, fill_value=False)
df.loc[mask, 'Test case ID'] = (~m).cumsum()
```

Comment: Sorry @jezrael, but could you kindly explain it in more detail? Currently, I don't get your answer

Comment: @GiaHuy - Your data are in one DataFrame? What means `I don't get your answer` ? What is necessary explain more?

Comment: Yes, all my data is in one data frame. When I said `I don't get your answer` I meant that your response set all the `Test case ID` values to 0. I attempted to follow your code, but I am new to visualizing data with pandas, so I didn't fully comprehend your explanation.